# How can I get a traceback for a bad menu.py in Nuke?

Tags: python, windows, traceback, nuke

I'm using a [Nuke startup script](https://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/nuke/developers/100/pythondevguide/startup.html) located at `\\server\path\menu.py`. First I add `\\server\path\` to my `NUKE_PATH` environment variable, then I launch Nuke.

After the splash screen, I get the following error:

> \\server\path\menu.py : error interpreting this plugin

...and then Nuke terminates. There is no logfile in `%HOME%\.nuke`

How can I get a traceback to see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Surround everything in a `try/except`.  The file probably looks like this

```
def main():
    # code and stuff
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So just do

```
def main():
    # code and stuff
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()

        # Or you can save to a file
        with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(traceback.format_exc())
```